# How to insert python variable into Latex matrix in Jupyter notebook markdown cell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, latex, jupyter

So, I am trying to make a Jupyter notebook that is slightly interactive in which I can change the number value of a variable, and then use that variable in a Markdown cell to display a Latex matrix like so:

[image: Image with Latex Code]

And that cell displays this:

[image: Image after running code]

I don't know why that spanID thing is showing or how to get rid of it. I already have NBextensions installed and in that Markdown cell if I just type `{{a_0}}` then when I run that cell it just displays `1` like it should. But the moment I put it within the latex matrix, then I get the error. Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The solution I applied for the problem is to create Latex objects in the code cells and displaying them in the markdown cells with Python Markdown extension of the Jupyter notebook extensions. For example, a code cell can have:

```
from IPython.display import Latex as lt

# Room_length [m]
l_rl = 30
l_rl_lt = lt(rf"$l_\mathrm{{rl}}={l_rl}\ \mathsf{{m}}$")
```

and the markdown cell can have:

```
The room has length size {{l_rl_lt}}.
```

Comment: [Can't make it work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVbGk.png).

Answer (score 0):

Since variables in markdown cells are still not natively supported and it cannot be done without specific extensions (this is especially a problem in JupyterLab).
It is worth mentioning that you can also print the matrix directly from the code cell.

As an example, I will use [function from my gist](https://gist.github.com/KMChris/8fd878826453c3d55814b3293c7b084c).
It basically looks like this:

[image: LaTeX in Jupyter]